# Ajax, merge or extend data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to pass data to a php function, but I can't merge the data. I'm trying to have a progress bar while loading.

This is the code:

#### AJAX

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit_button', function(event) {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        var tmp = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            tmp[i] = 'hue';
        }
        data[i] = tmp;
    };

    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                    $('.progress').css({
                        width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                    });
                    if (percentComplete === 1) {
                        $('.progress').addClass('hide');
                    }
                }
            }, false);

            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                    $('.progress').css({
                        width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                    });
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'my_action',
            nonce: $('#my_nonce').text()
        },
        url: ajaxurl,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },

    });
});
```

#### PHP

```php
function my_action() {
    if (wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['nonce'], 'my_nonce')) {
        wp_die('WORKS');
    } else {
        wp_die('BUSTED');
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
```

The problem is, I can't merge `var data = [];` with `{action: 'my_action', nonce: $('#my_nonce').text()}`.

I tried data push ie `data.push({ action: 'my_action' });
data.push({ nonce: $('#my_nonce').text() });` but it doesnt work. Also tried `$.extend()` but without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: data is an `Array`, `{action: 'my_action'}` an object. It make no sense to `merge` them. Can you add the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: what data are you try to merge?

Comment: What is that data array even for? None of this makes any sense

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why are you also using native `XMLHttpRequest` requests? This will break for IE and other older browser versions.

Comment: What on earth is the for-loop good for?

Comment: Well, if i write `type: 'POST',
  data: {action: 'my_action', nonce: $('#my_nonce').text()},` the function it works, but it doesnt work the progress bar. But if i write `type: 'POST', data: data,` it works the progress bar but it doesnt work the function. My point is to make them work both.

Comment: Why on earth you are not using jQuery AJAX even after using jQuery functions??

Answer (score 0):

I've made some quick tests, Have you received the same results?

[image]

Comment: Can you get the same result with the HTML part.
`<style>
.progress {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 0;
    height: 5px;
    background: red;
    transition: width .3s;
}
.progress.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.3s;
}
</style>
<div class="progress"></div>
<button type="submit"  id="submit_button" >Search</button>
<span id="my_nonce" class="hidden"><?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_nonce' ); ?></span>`